# Story Teller and SOAP UI testing tool experience

Tags: .net, testing

We are currently using Fitnesse for sub system testing. [All our applications are in c#.net]
We are having lot of issues around Fitnesse.
We are planning to use another software for subsystem testing.
I recently heard about Story Teller subsystem testing and SOAP UI test tool.
Does anyone have any experience (good/bad) with these tools?
It would be great if I could get at least URL's which could point me to these tools.
I have posted on stackoverflow many times questions about tools related to subsystem testing, never got a convincing answer.
It would be great if we could collect the experiences about "Story Teller" and "Soap UI" here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Story Teller](http://storyteller.tigris.org/) is being developed by [Jeremy D. Miller](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/) and first version is released as a preview. I think it is too early to count on this tool at this point.

[SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a mature tool with many helpful features.